# How to use fingerprint authentication in android app? What are the limitations?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to use fingerprint authentication along with location data to track work progress. I tried implementing android sensor with not much success.

I want to build an app that can use both inbuilt fingerprint sensor of mobile as well as external sensor. Also please provide explanation if there is any limitations put by android system.

Answer (score 1):

The Fingerprint Authentication is offered from Android 6.0+. It is not supported for lower versions.

Refer this example for Fingerprint Authentication (for above android 6.0)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

I also found a easy tutorial that might help you in this regard.

https://dzone.com/articles/android-fingerprint-authentication-tutorial

For previous android version each company such as Samsung, Motorola, HTC created its own API and SDK to access to fingerprint sensor.

For instance Samsung provide a SDK http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass

> Pass SDK allows you to use fingerprint recognition features in your application. With Pass SDK, you can provide reinforced security, since you can identify whether the current user actually is the authentic owner of the device.

Comment: Newer Android Versions support more Authentication Methods.

Also please note: within Android you can just check if an enrolled user has authenticated using a fingerprint. You do not get information which Fingerprint or which user.